# MySQL: Update a "sort" column accoreding to ORDER BY

Tags: mysql, select, columnsorting

Fully edited:
My query has 2 columns from 2 tables: filename and sortorder.

Full tables are done here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8c0507

Example:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 t1
  LEFT JOIN table2 t2
    ON t1.idmd5 = t2.imgid
ORDER BY t2.filename
WHERE t1.anotherid = "123456";
```

Output:

```
filename-01.jpg   - 12
filename-02.jpg   - 73
filename-03.jpg   - 1
filename-12.jpg   - 63
filename-24.jpg   - 99
```

Now, the "sortorder" column should be re-set according to the ORDER BY - output, it should start at 1.

Expected result:

```
filename-01.jpg   - 1
filename-02.jpg   - 2
filename-03.jpg   - 3
filename-12.jpg   - 4
filename-24.jpg   - 5
```

How to achieve that?

Comment: Do you want an `UPDATE`  operation ? Or `SELECT` query?

Comment: As UPDATE I think. The content in sortorder should be changed / recounted

Answer (score 3):

Here's the query:

- Assigning a row number to each file name after sorting in `ASCENDING
  ORDER`.
- Later making an `INNER JOIN` between the table alias `t` and your
  table `YT` on matching filename and setting the `t.rn (row number/new
  sort order)` to the `YT.sortOrder` column.

---

```
UPDATE 
your_table YT 
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT 
        fileName,
        @rowNumber := @rowNumber + 1 AS rn
    FROM your_table , (SELECT @rowNumber := 0) var
    ORDER BY fileName ASC
) AS t
ON YT.fileName = t.fileName
SET YT.sortOrder = t.rn;
```

[**Demo** *Before update*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/82892/1/0)

---

***Facing problems to access SQL FIDDLE***

**TEST SCHEMA(with data):**

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `your_table`;
CREATE TABLE `your_table` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `filename` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `sortOrder` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
INSERT INTO `your_table` VALUES ('1', 'f1', '12');
INSERT INTO `your_table` VALUES ('2', 'f2', '73');
INSERT INTO `your_table` VALUES ('3', 'f3', '1');
INSERT INTO `your_table` VALUES ('4', 'f4', '63');
INSERT INTO `your_table` VALUES ('5', 'f5', '99');

SELECT 
*
FROM your_table;

id  filename   sortOrder
1      f1         12
2      f2         73
3      f3          1
4      f4         63
5      f5         99

**Now Run the above query**



SELECT 
*
FROM your_table;
```

**FINAL OUTPUT:**

```
id  filename   sortOrder
1      f1         1
2      f2         2
3      f3         3
4      f4         4
5      f5         5
```

**EDIT:** (*Based on the changes in the requirement*)

```
UPDATE 
tableone TOne 
INNER JOIN 
(
  SELECT
        t1.file_id,
        t2.IMG_FILENAME,
        @rowNumber := @rowNumber + 1 AS rn
    FROM
    tableone t1
    LEFT JOIN tabletwo t2 ON t1.FILE_ID = t2.IMG_ID
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rowNumber := 0) AS var
    ORDER BY t2.IMG_FILENAME ASC
) AS t
ON TOne.file_id = t.file_id
SET TOne.Order = t.rn;
```

**Test Data And Schema:**

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tableone`;
CREATE TABLE `tableone` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `order` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `file_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
INSERT INTO `tableone` VALUES ('1', '12', '1');
INSERT INTO `tableone` VALUES ('2', '73', '2');
INSERT INTO `tableone` VALUES ('3', '1', '3');
INSERT INTO `tableone` VALUES ('4', '63', '4');
INSERT INTO `tableone` VALUES ('5', '99', '5');


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tabletwo`;
CREATE TABLE `tabletwo` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `img_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `img_filename` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

INSERT INTO `tabletwo` VALUES ('1', '1', 'filename-01.jpg ');
INSERT INTO `tabletwo` VALUES ('2', '2', 'filename-02.jpg ');
INSERT INTO `tabletwo` VALUES ('3', '3', 'filename-03.jpg ');
INSERT INTO `tabletwo` VALUES ('4', '4', 'filename-04.jpg ');
INSERT INTO `tabletwo` VALUES ('5', '5', 'filename-05.jpg ');
```

**Run the above (`UPDATE`) query operation and see the result**

**BEFORE UPDATING**: [**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4a00d/3/0)

**AFTER UPDATING**: [**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/df8d33/1/0)

Comment: The question was too abstracted, my fault. Filename and sortorder coming out of 2 tables, so the "real" statement is:

    SELECT t1.ORDER, t2.IMG_FILENAME
    FROM tableone t1    
    LEFT JOIN tabletwo t2
    ON t1.FILE_ID = t2.IMG_ID

How to handle that? Sorry for that...

Comment: It's really frustrating that you didn't tell it in the first time. Now would you please update your question to your new requirement?

Comment: So, the update would take place in `tableOne`? Better share the `table structure code` of these two tables.

Comment: Please have a look at the updated answer under **EDIT** Section.

Comment: Doesn't work because you have no ORDER BY clause in it.
It works in your example just because the SELECT output is "ordered" correctly

Comment: Forgot to put an order by clause in the edit. Now updated in the query under edit section. Try now

Comment: Updated the fiddle now. Please let me know if it's okay now.

Comment: Nope, doesn't work on my real table. I guess because the ORDER clause is applied *after* the select statement - that means the counter isn't correct, because it's counting before sort ordering.
I think it would need another select query to get it work.
However, I'll find another way to recount that column. I thought there could be an easy way, but it doesn't work.
Anyway, thanks for your great and fast support!